# Ef Code first - Create table per relation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have some classes with one to many relationship like below:

```
public class A
{
    public int Ax { get; set; }
    public int Ay { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Bx { get; set; }
    public List<A> By { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Cx { get; set; }
    public List<A> Cy { get; set; }
}
```

I need when A have one-to-many relation it generate table for that relationship with out need create concrete class like AB or AC so in this example final database should have **4 table** some thing like:
TABLE B (id, bx) 1----->1..* TABLE BA ( B_id*, ax, ay )
TABLE C (id, cx) 1----->1..* TABLE CA ( C_id*, ax, ay )
* Required Field

and EF configuration like:

```
public class AConfiguration : ComplexTypeConfiguration<A>
{
    public AConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable(); // this line force all relationship create table
    }
}

public class BConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<B>
{
    public BConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("B");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        HasRequired(b=>b.By).WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}

public class CConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<C>
{
    public CConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("C");
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        HasRequired(c=>c.Cy).WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

How can I do configure EF to generate database schema from my class?

Comment: thanks for your response. is there any way I create overload function like ToTable(p => p.By) and that function clone A & AConfiguration and set type name to AB and finally EF create table by Clone of A & AConfiguration ?

Comment: the only way to have a link table is a many to many multiplicity. Are you sure of your multiplicity: One A record can be related to a maximum of one B record ?

Comment: One A should only related to One B, but One B can related to zero or more A.  If I create many to many relation I should create unique A_id constraint on AB & AC table. this approach have two problem first if domain have many relation to A class on database table A grow very fast. second I think EF have not option for controlling many-to-many intermediate table to add unique costraint.

Comment: so you do not need a relation table, a single column in tableA is enough to link one A to 0 or one B, and allows B to be linked to 0 or many A.

Comment: If A only on relation with B this table is correct but in this simple scenario A have relation with B & C so table should like this (A_id*, ax, ay, B_id*, C_id*) (* is required) and A can only for B or C. so single table for A can't usable.

Comment: In this case, you should have something like a base (eventually abstract) `class BC`, then `class A : BC`, `classB : BC` and finally class A { public BC bc {get; set;} } an you should choose between TPT and TPH.